# Unble to Test Graphapi in postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, azure, graph-api, postman

I am working on graph api and able to test few thing graphapi and Postman but few of them not working in postman same query is working in Graphapi explorer and please find the below attached screens shots

[image: postman]

[image: graphapi]

Answer (score 0):

Test with Delegated permissions(On behalf of a user), works fine.

[image]

Get User Access Token(Post).

[image]

Reference guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tg-OBdv_8o&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I have granted the Admin Privileges  even not working

Comment: I get the token by (Post Get User Access Token which based on app id&secret and user credential), try a different list also.

Answer (score 0):

I have granted the Admin Privileges even not working

[image: Permission]